# Update DB based on Select query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to update `product.status` to zero (0) in my database when certain criteria are matched.

I have tried this SQL but I can't get it to work. Anyone with an idea?

```
UPDATE product p
SET p.status = 0
FROM product_to_store p2s, product p
WHERE p2s.product_id = p.product_id AND p.quantity=0 AND p.status=1 AND p2s.store_id=0
```

---

```
DB product (product_id, quantity, status)
DB product_to_store (product_id, store_id)
```

Comment: r u getting any errors?

Comment: #1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Comment: Try adopting the correct syntax

Answer (score -1):

Try with this query:

```
Update product p set p.status=0 from product_to_store p2s 
join product p on p2s.product_id = p.product_id 
where p.status=1 and p.quantity=0
```

Comment: What is the field name in product table for Id? Can you please update your database schema for both of these table?

Comment: I have added the fields above.

Comment: Haven't you set product_id as a primary key in Product table?